# How to make a rolling gradient column for a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series like:

```
            United Kingdom
Time (CET)                
2020-02-15         1739771
2020-02-16         1649750
2020-02-17         1887394
2020-02-18         1922006
2020-02-19         1957194
2020-02-20         1878259
2020-02-21         1890076
2020-02-22         1677928
2020-02-23         1688218
2020-02-24         1948947
[...]
```

I would like to make a new column which is the gradient of a rolling window of length 5. So the first entry will be the gradient of a straight line fitted through `[1739771, 1649750, 1887394, 1922006, 1957194]`, the second the gradient of a straight line fitted through `[1649750, 1887394, 1922006, 1957194, 1878259]` and so on.

The code to fit a straight line and hence return the gradient is:

```
import numpy as np
Polynomial = np.polynomial.Polynomial
def fitcurve(sequence):
    poly = Polynomial.fit(range(len(sequence)), sequence, 1)
    a = poly.convert().coef
    return a[0], a[1]  #  a[1] is the gradient we want.
```

The first 4 entries in the new column will have to be NaNs which is ok.

How can I make this new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) function. Something like this should work:

```
df["UK Rolling"] = df["United Kingdom"].rolling(5).apply(lambda x: fitcurve(x)[1])
```